# gethostbyname says No such service is known. The service cannot be found in the specified name space

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2, windows-11

This simple piece of code in Windows results in an annoying debug message printed by `gethostbyname`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    hostent* he = gethostbyname("www.stackoverflow.com");
    char* ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)he->h_addr_list[0]);
    printf(ip);
}
```

it says:

```
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(550)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FFCFC1FC759: (caller: 00007FFD2856388E) LogHr(1) tid(6e14) 8007277C No such service is known. The service cannot be found in the specified name space.
```

I'm on Windows. using visual studio 2019. How can I omit that? Currently, I'm debugging and because my log is filled completely with this message, it's hard to find desired logs.

Comment: I know I can filter logs :)

Comment: @user438383 c++

Comment: From the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-gethostbyname): *Otherwise, it returns a null pointer and a specific error number can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.* You should check for errors instead of just accessing the pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh It doesn't have any error. gethostbyname prints that log. not using the result.

Comment: gethostbyname is deprecated. Try using getaddrinfo instead.

Comment: Anything `gethostbyname()` does internally is outside of your control. You can't stop it from logging internal messages, if that is what it wants to do. Lots of system functions have various levels of internal logging.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought I set something wrong.

Comment: Are you using Windows 11, by chance?

Comment: @J... yep i am !

Comment: @s4eed  Thanks.  I don't have a solution for you, but I've also noticed similar pollution in the debug output in a large project recently test built in Win11 - a suite of COM errors like this one, mostly related to WinAPI calls into AD/LDAP as welll as to the namespace service provider (as you've shown here).  The project is built in Delphi, but has about two decades worth of dependencies and something down there is generating hundreds of these debug output errors on launch.  Oddly, we see nothing broken in the app itself but I haven't tracked down the cause.  Something changed in Win11...

Comment: @J... Exactly like me. I didn't have this log in Windows 10 but I do in Windows 11. In comments, someone said it's deprecated.

Comment: I get similar debug output when calling [`ADsGetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsgetobject) and that is not deprecated...

Answer (score 8):

The behaviour you're seeing seems to be due to [Layered Service Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/categorizing-layered-service-providers-and-applications) being [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features) as of Win11 (and potentially an upcoming Win10 update).

`GetHostByName` is listed as deprecated, but [`GetHostName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-gethostname) is not and also displays the same behaviour.  In both cases the method queries any available namespace service providers first and then falls back to querying the NetBIOS name if none are found.  As of Win11 it seems the call to enumerate the namespace service providers fails internally, generating the debug output you see.