# Windows 11 and QT5.14: "8007277C No such service is known" when making request to Microsoft Server 2016 Datacenter

Tags: qt, qt5, windows-server, windows-server-2016, windows-11

We have a data server running on an AWS instance of a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. I have just compiled the program and while running in debug mode am trying to make requests to the server to return some information. However, on each attempt to make a request to the server, I am presented with the following in the QT Creator debug window:

```
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(550)\nlansp_c.dll!5C5C85D4: (caller: 75EBCD00) LogHr(3) tid(8148) 8007277C No such service is known. The service cannot be found in the specified name space.
```

eg of type of request sent:

```
QUrl("http://server.com/customer/v0/index.php/?object=reset_password&username=blah&email=email@email.com")
```

I've only come across two other relevant calls to this error:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26365
- [gethostbyname says No such service is known. The service cannot be found in the specified name space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694417/gethostbyname-says-no-such-service-is-known-the-service-cannot-be-found-in-the)

Both of which state the following about Windows 11:

> The behaviour you're seeing seems to be due to Layered Service Providers being deprecated as of Win11 (and potentially an upcoming Win10 update).

However neither list a solution/workaround. Is there a fix that can be implemented for this for windows 11 machines?

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use QNetworkAccessManager() on Qt and I got this error "The service could not be found in the specified namespace". And I'm on Windows 11. Have you found a solution...?

Comment: Hi @Juan sorry for the late reply. I only just came across this old post I made. I've been going through my old chat logs and commit history to see if I can remember how/if I solved this. I would suggest to check the URL created and follow `namespaceprovider.cpp`, using that URL in an application like Postman, as well as following the backend API. Sorry I can't be more help. If all else fails, try reinstalling QT.