# Wt or Qt Application run time Error on Windows 11

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, wt

When Start Application Following error occured.
runtime error:

```
onecore\net\netprofiles\service\src\nsp\dll\namespaceserviceprovider.cpp(550)\nlansp_c.dll!00007FFD2065D93D: (caller: 00007FFD310BACF6) LogHr(2) tid(4380) 8007277C No such service is known. The service cannot be found in the specified name space.

Exception at 0x7ffd2ede5b0c, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x81 (first chance) at C:\jenkins\workspace\wt-winlease\build-amd64-14.3\wt-src\src\http\Configuration.C:463

Exception at 0x7ffd2ede5b0c, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x81 (first chance) at C:\jenkins\workspace\wt-win_4.10-release\build-amd64-14.3\wt-src\src\http\Configuration.C:301

Exception at 0x7ffd2ede5b0c, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x81 (first chance) in ntdll!RtlCaptureContext2
```

and the following Debug trace screenshot

**

- Qt: 5.15.2
- Wt: 4.10 Platform: Windows 11 x64
- Compiler: MSVC 2022 Community ( 17.9.34622.214 )
  **

[image: Debug Trace]

Comment: No idea, but you need use the debugger to stop at line 463 of Configuration.C and see what is happening there.

Comment: Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694417/gethostbyname-says-no-such-service-is-known-the-service-cannot-be-found-in-the), it might report your exact problem.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh, this occured bye not just Wt library, also Qt and Mongocxx library. Maybe there are more. i think this releated to win11